# Contentful.com Webhook Creation

Tags: json, curl, webhooks, contentful

I'm trying to create a Webhook on Contentful.com via their Content Management API. Command as follows (note that I've tweaked respective ID's for security):

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/vnd.contentful.management.v1+json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer c8c3ef46d5dbfe3c841a3b4bff1ee89449669ffd407d1a62c7a0ecbad9c3120' -H 'Content-Length: 33' 'https://api.contentful.com/spaces/du8mcuj2d5la/webhook_definitions/1CtkR6S5oUqWywgEO2i0xx' -d '{"url":"https://xxx.parseapp.com"}'
```

It appears no matter what URL (other than `https://www.example.com`) I use in the final object I get the following response:

```
{
  "sys":{
    "type":"Error",
    "id":"InvalidJsonRequestBody"
  },
  "requestId":"85f-1338857905",
  "message":"The body you sent is not valid JSON."
}
```

I've validated with Paw (`http://luckymarmot.com/paw`) that the endpoint pass accepts inbound POST requests and (returns a 200 response code). Just to stress if I switch out `https://xxx.parseapp.com` to `https://www.example.com` it creates the webhook. Anything else it appears to complain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the issue is quite simple:
The payload length does not match the `Content-Length` header.

`{"url":"https://xxx.parseapp.com"}` is 34 bytes, but you've set the header explicitly to `-H 'Content-Length: 33'`. (33 is only true for the *example.com* example.)

If you adjust the length to `-H 'Content-Length: 34'` it should work fine.
Also you could leave this header out when experimenting with `curl` as it will automatically set it to the correct value (check with `-v` option).

In general most HTTP clients/libraries should set the Content-Length header on their own when doing POST/PUT requests.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you...always obvious in hindsight :)